# HTML/JS User inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to retrieve a text input from an input field using html and js.

HTML

```
<div class="inputarea">
        <input type="text" value ='' id='myInput' placeholder="What do I need to do?"> 
        <button onclick='todolist().submit()'>SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
function todolist(){
    function first(){
        window.open("todolist.html")
    }
    function submit(){
        var userinput = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
        console.log(userinput);
    }
}
```

When I press submit the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sam.

Comment: did you import your js file in the html?

Comment: Because todolist returns undefined. That is not how classes work in JavaScript

Comment: @Mox in that case todolist would be undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning the functions

```js
function todolist() {
  function first() {
    window.open("todolist.html")
  }

  function submit() {
    var userinput = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    console.log(userinput);
  }
  return {first, submit};
}
```

```html
<div class="inputarea">
  <input type="text" value='' id='myInput' placeholder="What do I need to do?">
  <button onclick='todolist().submit()'>SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably **todolist** should be class (EcmaScript 6+). Or you ment to return object from **todolist** function:

```js
function todolist(){
  return {
     first(){
        window.open("todolist.html")
    },
     submit(){
        var userinput = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
        console.log(userinput);
    } 
  }
}

todolist().submit();
```

Comment: Ok ill put it into a class

Comment: @SamuelWash, Note that not every browser supports ES6 class syntax. You may need some tool like Babel to make it work on browsers like Internet Explorer. Check this out: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class